# Can anyone explain the differential equation for the sunflower seed pattern>

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It seems that there is an algorithm to generate the sunflower seed pattern based on the golden ratio. From this article in the [Irish Times](https://thatsmaths.com/2014/06/05/sunflowers-and-fibonacci-models-of-efficiency/):

> A simple mathematical description of the geometry of sunflower seed
>   patterns was devised by Helmut Vogel (1979). He defined the positions
>   of the seeds, using polar coordinates (r, θ), by
>
> r(n) = √n         and         θ(n) = n φ
>
> where φ ≈ 137.5º is the golden angle. Thus, as n increases by one, the
>   position rotates through the golden angle and the radius increases as
>   the square root of n. All points are on a curve called the generative
>   spiral (r = √θ), a form of Fermat spiral which winds ever-tighter as
>   it curls outwards.

But that doesn't explain how the sunflower actually does it. Now someone has come up with a differential equation that claims to generate the pattern. From the same article:[image]

The equation comes from [a paper by Pennybacker and Newell](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.248104) which I don't have access to (and probably wouldn't understand if I did).

Is this for real? Does this differential equation really work? And if so, can anyone give a physical explanation of what the individual terms are doing? I don't mean "explain to me what the del operator does", I mean like "why do you subtract the cube of the hormone concentration..." etc. Any insights?

Comment: Please see [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://math.arizona.edu/~anewell/publications/197newell.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiJwJLAqqbRAhWMNI8KHS--DOMQFghYMAc&usg=AFQjCNFSVAo9qeEmVK4BXHh5uv44887SFg).

Comment: Thanks, Rohan, I can see it's a beautifully written paper but it's beyond my comprehension. Maybe some other people will have insights into this, or will benefit from a deeper discussion.